# Using geom_raster(), why is it that some tile values(colors) do not appear correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-raster

I'm fairly new to R and I'm having some trouble with creating a heatmap using the geom_raster() function. So I am working on the tidytuesday challenge this week and I would like to create a heat map to show if hosting the race poses an advantage to the host team. I look at the metrics: *team_name* and *pole* for the *x* and *y* values respectively. I then fill the graph with the *host* variable to see if there are any trends with each team, its finishing position, and if they were the host of the race.

Below is a snippet of code I used to create the heatmap and the heatmap itself. I tidy'd up the data by this point which is the reason for the funky data name.

```
pole_position <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13", "P14", "P15", "P16")

ggplot(data = clean_marbles_2, mapping = aes(x = team_name, y = pole, fill = host)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = pole_position) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Team name", y = "Finish placement", title = "Does hosting the race affect finish placement?")
```

[image: The above code provides this graphic.]

At first I thought this was a pretty cool graphic, but I soon realized that it was missing some of the 'Yes' hosts. There should be sixteen different teal boxes in this graphic but there's only 11.

I then faceted the graph to figure out if it recognizes the data that was entered. Below is the code and a photo of the produced graphic. pole_position's value does not change between the two graphs.

```
ggplot(data = clean_marbles_2, mapping = aes(x = team_name, y = pole, fill = host)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = pole_position) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Team name", y = "Finish placement", title = "Does hosting the race affect finish placement?") +
  facet_wrap(~host)
```

[image: faceted graphic]

As you can see, all sixteen of the blue tiles appear in the 'Yes' area. I am thoroughly confused as to why the previous graphic only recorded 11 of the 16 blue tiles.

My question is: Why don't all of the blue tiles appear in the first graphic?

Any help and/or constructive criticism is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is a link to the tidytuesday Github repository: [here.](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2020/2020-06-02)

EDIT:

Here's what I did to Tidy the data, please don't berate me for doing anything wrong, I would love to learn any way to boost my coding efficiency.

```
# Read in the data from the github repo

marbles <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-06-02/marbles.csv')

# Set the correct point & pole values

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P1'] = 25

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 25] = 'P1'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P2'] = 18

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 18] = 'P2'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P3'] = 15

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 15] = 'P3'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P4'] = 12

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 12] = 'P4'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P5'] = 10

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 10] = 'P5'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P6'] = 8

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 8] = 'P6'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P7'] = 6

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 6] = 'P7'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P8'] = 4

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 4] = 'P8'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P9'] = 2

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 2] = 'P9'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P10'] = 1

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 1] = 'P10'

marbles$points[marbles$pole == 'P11'] = 0

marbles$pole[marbles$points == 0] = 'P11'

# replace any excess and incorrect pole/point values to align with my scale.

marbles[186, 8] = 'P10'

marbles[186, 9] = 1

# Replace the pole values for the 0 point scores
# This was done for many more values than what is seen here.

marbles[252,8] = 'P12'

marbles[253,8] = 'P13'

marbles[254,8] = 'P14'

marbles[255,8] = 'P15'

marbles[256,8] = 'P16'

# Remove the notes and source sections of the tidy data

clean_marbles = subset(marbles, select = -c(notes, source))

# Create a clean subset without any NA values

clean_marbles_2 = na.omit(clean_marbles)
```

I am aware that this is extremely tedious. You can see the points and pole corresponding values in the code i've included above. I was attempting to make the data more uniform thinking that it would be easier to visualize afterwards, but I guess not.

Comment: I think your problem is with the data, not the plot as such. Ask yourself what happens if Thunderbirds comes second in a week when they were hosting, but also comes second in a different week when they weren't hosting (which seems to have happened) Then you will get a blue square plotted but a pink square will be plotted right over it. You can confirm this by setting `alpha = 0.5` in `geom_raster`

Comment: @AllanCameron I hadn' thought of that. Great insight, thanks! One question though, would it be possible to somehow lay the teal squares over the pink squares? I'm thinking that would mitigate the problem...

Comment: @ian I've applied `alpha = 0.5` to my `geom_raster` and while it does make the entire graph more transparent, it's difficult to distinguish whether both colors are in the area or not. I'll try the pre-computation then the transparency change. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with how you have tidied the data. If we plot with the raw data in this reprex, your error doesn't appear:

```
library(ggplot2)

url <- paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/",
              "tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-06-02/marbles.csv")

raw_marbles  <- read.csv(url)
pole_position <- paste0("P", 1:16)

p <- ggplot(raw_marbles, aes(x = team_name, y = pole, fill = host)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = pole_position) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Team name", y = "Finish placement", 
       title = "Does hosting the race affect finish placement?")

p
```

[image]

It appears some of the tiles are "missing", but that's because they have no position assigned in the raw data. We can also confirm the correct number of blue squares is displayed here:

```
p + facet_wrap(.~host)
```

[image]
So I guess the question is "what have you done to the raw data?". Showing how you got to `clean_marbles_2` in your question would probably allow us to solve this issue.

Incidentally, there does seem to be an effect of hosting versus non hosting. You can do a Wilcox test to show it:

```
NoYes <- lapply(split(raw_marbles$pole, raw_marbles$host), 
                function(x) na.omit(as.numeric(substr(x, 2, 3))))

wilcox.test(NoYes[[1]], NoYes[[2]])

#>  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  NoYes[[1]] and NoYes[[2]]
#> W = 280, p-value = 0.04911
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

So it seems the pole numbers were significantly higher (i.e. closer to P16) for the hosts.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using the Wilcox test to show this? How do you know to use the Wilcox test as opposed to anything else? Also, thanks for the explanation of everything, helped a lot.

Comment: @BrettVogelsang   I'm using the Wilcox test because the pole positions are ordered but not proportional or continuous. They therefore have to be ranked to do a statistical comparison. You have two groups whose ranks you want to compare, and a Wilcox.test is just a way of measuring the probability that two ranked groups both come from the same population (I.e. that  there is no difference between them.) That's just stats knowledge rather than R specific knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `geom_tile` instead of `geom_raster` using filter and two calls to `geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(data = clean_marbles_2 %>% filter(host == "No"), mapping = aes(x = team_name, y = pole)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "#F8766D") +
  geom_tile(data = clean_marbles_2 %>% filter(host == "Yes"), fill = "#00BFC4") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = pole_position) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Team name", y = "Finish placement", title = "Does hosting the race affect finish placement?")
```

[image]

We need to use `geom_tile` because `geom_raster` will shift around the rows.

Here's an approach to cleaning up the data with `dplyr::recode`. The `!!!` operator expands a list into arguments to be passed to a function. This is needed because `recode` expects individual arguments.

We can use `ifelse` to only replace the NA in `pole`. Since we aren't using score, I didn't bother recoding that one, but you could easily go in reverse.

```
clean_marbles_2 <- marbles %>% 
  mutate(pole = 
           ifelse(is.na(pole),
                  recode(marbles2$points,
                         !!!c(`26` = "P1", `25` = "P1", `19` = "P2",
                              `18` = "P2", `16` = "P3", `15` = "P3",
                              `13` = "P4", `12` = "P4", `11` = "P5",
                              `10` = "P5", `8` = "P6", `6` = "P7",
                              `4` = "P8", `2` = "P9", `1` = "P10",
                              `0` = "P11")),
                        pole)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-notes, -source)
```